# Spark how to read from multiple Elastic Search clusters

Tags: scala, apache-spark, elasticsearch

I need to read data from two different Elastic Search clusters. one for logs and one for products data and I tried to put different `sparkConf()` when creating `SparkSession` but it seems it works only with the first SparkSession I created

```
val config1 = new SparkConf().setAppName("test")
  .set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true")
  .set("es.index.auto.create", "true")
  .set("es.nodes.discovery", "false")
  .set("es.nodes.wan.only", "true")
  .set("es.nodes.client.only", "false")
  .set("es.nodes", s"$esNode1:$esPort1")

val config2 = new SparkConf().setAppName("test")
  .set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true")
  .set("es.index.auto.create", "true")
  .set("es.nodes.discovery", "false")
  .set("es.nodes.wan.only", "true")
  .set("es.nodes.client.only", "false")
  .set("es.nodes", s"$esNode2:$esPort2")

val session1 = SparkSession.builder.master('local').config(config1).getOrCreate()
val session2 = SparkSession.builder.master('local').config(config2).getOrCreate()

session1.read.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql").load(path)
session2.read.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql").load(path)
```

it seems spark does not support for multiple sessions with the same format because I am using the same SparkSession with Mysql(jdbc) too and it works well. is there an alternative way to get data from multiple ElasticSearch clusters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create only one session per Spark application. Then read 2 DataFrames this way:

```
  val config = new SparkConf().setAppName("test")
    .set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true")
    .set("es.index.auto.create", "true")
    .set("es.nodes.discovery", "false")
    .set("es.nodes.wan.only", "true")
    .set("es.nodes.client.only", "false")

  val session = SparkSession.builder.master("local").config(config).getOrCreate

  val df1 = session.read.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")
    .option("es.nodes", s"$esNode1:$esPort1").load(path)

  val df2 = session.read.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")
    .option("es.nodes", s"$esNode2:$esPort2").load(path)
```